# Why System.out.println prints the elements of an arraylist and not the hashcode of the object?

Tags: java, arraylist

I didn't override `toString()` so I am confused. Isn't an `ArrayList` an object like arrays since they are created using `new`?

Example:

```
    ArrayList <String> arri= new ArrayList();
    String one="one";
    String two=new String ("two");
    arri.add(one);
    arri.add(two);
    System.out.println(arri);

    //output:
    //[one, two]
```

Thanks

Comment: JavaDoc is your friend. If you go to [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and scroll down the method list, you'll see it inherits [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString--) from `AbstractCollection`, which handles this.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "Isn't an arraylist an object like arrays since they are created using new"... `ArrayList` is just another class, as far as Java is concerned.

Comment: thanks for the answers.  however why my question got down voted? cant beginners ask questions here? thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayList` (unlike arrays) overrides `toString()` and `String` overrides `toString()`, so printing an `ArrayList<String>` displays all the `String`s of that `List`.

Answer (score 4):

*You* don't have to override `toString()`... the object you're calling it on does. You're calling `toString()` on an `ArrayList`, and `ArrayList` overrides `toString`... or rather, [`AbstractCollection` does](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString--), and `ArrayList` inherits the implementation:

> Returns a string representation of this collection. The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma and space). Elements are converted to strings as by `String.valueOf(Object)`.